# Can't get full resolution with Dell U3011 monitor

Tags: drivers, graphics, dell, 13.10

Can't get full resolution with the Dell U3011 monitor. 
The machine is a Lenovo M92p which has integrated graphics (HD 4000).
The OS is ubuntu 13.10.

Any idea how to get the full resolution of 2560 x 1600 pixels?
The choices in the control panel for Displays only get up to 1920 x 1200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Intel graphics does not support dual-link, therefore 1920x1200 is the
> maximum for DVI and HDMI, 2560x1440 is only possible with a
> displayport port. This is stated in every specification sheet.
>
> http://communities.intel.com/message/189170

Have you tried a DisplayPort cable? I use one VGA and one DisplayPort with my X220 successfully (although with two monitors, not one large one).

Comment: Yes, a DisplayPort cable is what I use!

Comment: Besides, doesn't the absence of a 2560 x 1600 choice in the control panel indicate a driver issue, as opposed to a cable inadequacy?

Comment: Finally figured it out: it was ignoring the DisplayPort cable connection. Turns out the Dell monitor has a Power button and many LEDs, but the LEDs are themselves buttons even though they don't look clickable. Anyway, by clicking the LEDs one can change the input and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Tested all ports with my MacBook Pro. 
Results:

- DVI conneection - 1600 x...;
- HDMI connection - 1980 x ....;
- DisplayPort connection - 2560 x...;

The only port that can give you full resolution is the DisplayPort. Use DisplayPort is association with your MacBook Pro to get full resolution